# Unable to restart Apache service in WAMP on Windows 10

Tags: apache, wamp

I am unable to restart Apache in WAMP on my Windows 10 machine. I have an error message of the following:
[error message I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ureAE.png)

I'm running version 3.0.4 of WAMP and it is also 32 bit.

This is frustrating.

Comment: Did you read the INFO dialog in the install that say you need to make sure you have all the required MSVC Runtime libraries installed before installing WAMPServer? [Check here](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)

Comment: You dont need to install `Visual Studio` you only need the MSVC C++ Runtime libraries. _I didnt read it all_ [Well read it all here instead](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295)